# How to read from a text file to parallel arrays

Tags: c++

This is my text file: names.txt, surnames, tab, first names.

```
Olivier Vreda
chadwick    billy
Babajide    Pretty
Adams   Samantha
Venter  Charlie
Adams   Hein
Adams   Grace
deWet   Abel
```

Here is my program: names.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include "nameSort.h"
#include "nameSort.cpp"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Names Sorting"<<endl;
    cout<<"----------------------------"<<endl;
    string name, surn;
    int count=0;

    ifstream myfile("names.txt");
    while (myfile>>surn>>name)
    {
        count++:
    }
    surnames[count];
    firstnames[count];
    for (int i=0; i<=count; i++)
    {
        surnames[i]=myfile>>surn;
        firstnames[i]=myfile>>name;
    }
    myfile.close();

    cout<<"1. Sort names by surnames then first names"<<endl;
    cout<<"2. Sort names by first names then surnames"<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter your sorting choice: ";
    int choice;
    cin>>choice;
    if (choice==1)
    {
        cout<<"The sorted names by surnames then first names are:"<<endl;
        sortSurnameFirst(surnames, firstnames, count);
        displayNames(surnames, firstnames, count);

    }
    else if (choice==2)
    {
        cout<<"The sorted names by first names then surnames are:"<<endl;
        sortFirstnameFirst(surnames, firstnames, count);
        displayNames(surnames, firstnames, count);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My question: How do i read from my text file, and separate the surnames and names into two parallel arrays, surnames[size], and firstnames[size].
I'll be using a for loop. I've already counted how many elements in the text file as seen above. I've referred to other files, nameSort.h and nameSort.cpp which contain the functions to sort names. Those are seen to function correctly and i believe do not relate to the problem.

Comment: Don't use parallel arrays - difficult maintenance as you have discovered.  Place columns into a structure to model a record.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use parallel arrays.  Use a structure to model the record:

```
struct Person_Name
{
    std::string surname;
    std::string first_name;
};
```

Next, overload `operator>>` to read in the data into the structure:

```
struct Person_Name
{
    std::string surname;
    std::string first_name;

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& inp, Person_Name& p);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& inp, Person_Name& p)
{
    inp >> p.surname;
    inp >> p.first_name;
};
```

Now your input loop looks like this:

```
std::vector<Person_Name> people;
Person_Name name;
while (data_file >> name)
{
    people.push_back(name);
}
```

Placing the fields into a structure removes the issue of synchronization.
Also, the items are in one place.

**Edit 1: Support for Sorting**
You can overload `operator<` to provide a default ordering:

```
struct Person_Name
{
    std::string surname;
    std::string first_name;

    bool operator<(const Person_Name& other) const
    {
      if (surname != other.surname)
      {
          return surname < other.surname;
      }
      return first_name < other.first_name;
    }

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& inp, Person_Name& p);
};
```

This allows you to do things like:

```
std::vector<Person_Name> people;
//...
// Sort the container of names by surname.
std::sort(people.begin(), people.end());
```

For other comparisons you can write free standing functions:

```
bool Order_By_First_Name(const Person_Name& a,
                         const Person_Name& b)
{
   // Because Person_Name is a struct, the members can be freely accessed.
   if (a.first_name == b.first_name)
   {
       return a.surname < b.surname;
   }
   return a.first_name < b.first_name;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately its a requirement that i use parallel arrays in the assignment given.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with the shown code.

The first loop correctly counts the number of lines in the file. If, for example, there were two lines in the file, `count` will end up with the value 2.

The second loop, then, will iterate from 0 to 2, and thus attempt to read three lines from the file instead of two. Because it doesn't check for errors, and attempt will be made to pass references to the third elements of two-element arrays to `operator>>`. Although, in theory, `operator>>` is expected to fail, there won't technically be undefined behavior; still it's bad practice.

Finally, after the first loop reads through until the end of the array, the second loop simply starts iterating, assuming that, magically, it can read the same file from the beginning. Of course, nothing has been done to actually either seek the file stream back to the beginning of the file, or reopen the file. Every iteration of the second loop will fail to read anything.

Before running the second loop, the code should either reopen the file, or seek it back to its beginning.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (i % 2 == 0)
{
    // put in an array
}
else
{
    //put in the other array
}
```